# How to create a ToJSON / FromJSON entry for an algebraic data type with multiple constructors without arguments?

Tags: haskell

Given this data:

```
data A1 = A1 | A2 | A3
```

How can I create an instance for it?

```
instance ToJSON A1 where
  toJSON = ???

instance FromJSON A1 where
  parseJSON = ???
```

If it was a single constructor, I'd be able to do that, but I can't figure out how to do that with multiple ones which don't accept any parameters.

UPDATE:
For each constructor I have these errors:

```
my-app/src/Lib.hs:54:32:
    No instance for (ToJSON a1) arising from a use of ‘.=’
    The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance ToJSON UUID -- Defined in ‘Data.UUID.Aeson’
      instance ToJSON MyType -- Defined at src/Lib.hs:53:10
      instance ToJSON MyType2 -- Defined at src/Lib.hs:70:10
    In the expression: "tag" .= "A1"
    In the first argument of ‘object’, namely ‘["tag" .= "A1"]’
    In the expression: object ["tag" .= "A1"]

my-app/src/Lib.hs:54:35:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString a1)
      arising from the literal ‘"A1"’
    The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Data.String.IsString Value
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal’
      instance (a
                ~ bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString) =>
               Data.String.IsString
                 (attoparsec-0.13.0.1:Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Internal.Parser a)
        -- Defined in ‘attoparsec-0.13.0.1:Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8’
      instance Data.String.IsString
                 bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Builder
        -- Defined in ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Builder’
      ...plus 13 others
    In the second argument of ‘(.=)’, namely ‘"A1"’
    In the expression: "tag" .= "A1"
    In the first argument of ‘object’, namely ‘["tag" .= "A1"]’
```

Comment: The translation to JSON is up to you, usually I expect some sort of tag that indicates the constructor.  `toJSON A1 -> "{ 'tag' : 'A1' }"` so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems shown in the edit are all about type ambiguities which can be resolved by either using function application to make the types inferrable or adding type annotations.

- the right hand side of `.=` is a string literal so could be `String` or `Text` or others - annotate that with `::Text` or do as I do below and use `Text.pack . show`.
- The result of `.:` is polymorphic and the case patterns are all string literals which cause the same problem.  In the below I added `:: Text` to `tag`, thus removing the ambiguity.

The complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Control.Monad
import Data.Text as Text

data A1 = A1 | A2 | A3
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)


instance ToJSON A1 where
    toJSON a  = object ["tag" .= Text.pack (show a)]

instance FromJSON A1 where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        tag <- o .: "tag"
        case (tag :: Text) of
            "A1" -> return A1
            "A2" -> return A2
            "A3" -> return A3
            _    -> mzero
    parseJSON v = typeMismatch "A1" v
```

Comment: why did you  call it "tag" in json?

Comment: Its a common term.  You are 'tagging' the data structure to indicate which of the possible values of the union (sum type) is actually being expressed.  I basically said this in my first comment under your question.

Answer (score 3):

The `toJSON` and `parseJSON` functions take an argument each, the easiest for `toJSON` is probably:

```
instance ToJSON A1 where
    toJSON A1 = object ["tag" .= "A1"]
    toJSON A2 = object ["tag" .= "A2"]
    toJSON A3 = object ["tag" .= "A3"]
```

And then you just have to do the reverse in `parseJSON`:

```
instance FromJSON A1 where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        tag <- o .: "tag"
        case tag of
            "A1" -> return A1
            "A2" -> return A2
            "A3" -> return A3
            _    -> mzero
```

This just extracts the value at the key "tag" and then performs pattern matching on the Text returned to determine which constructor to use.

Comment: in `instance ToJSON A1 where` the A1 is the name of the class, whereas the next 3 are constructors, correct? That is, the 2nd A1 is a constructor.

Comment: @AlanCoromano The first `A1` is the name of the _data type_, `class` has specific meaning in Haskell that is different.  The next three are constructors.  It may be better to have `data A = A1 | A2 | A2` and `instance ToJSON A where ...` and `instance FromJSON A where ...`.

Comment: @AlanCoromano In your question you said `data A1 = A1 | A2 | A3` so the term `A1` is both a type and a constructor.  Your comment used the term `class` which means something else in Haskell.

Comment: @AlanCoromano You said that the first A1 is the name of the class.  Classes in Haskell are more like interfaces in Java, whereas classes in Java are more like data types in Haskell, although you can't translate them directly.  I think it might make it more clear if the name of your data type is `A` to avoid having the same name as any of the constructors of that type (although that is perfectly valid Haskell), that way it's easy to see which is which in code.

Comment: @bheklilr, I knowwwwwwwwwwwwww. The name of the class == the name of the "data".

Comment: I have plenty of error in your code, any ideas? See my updae.

Comment: @AlanCoromano Put `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` before your module declaration.  Aeson doesn't use the `String` type very much, most people don't because it's very inefficient compared to `Data.Text` or `Data.ByteString`.  That language directive will allow your string literals to act as any string-y type.

Comment: @AlanCoromano As for your comment about the name of the class being the name of the data, you should use the proper names for things in the programming language you're using.  `data A` and `class A` have very, very different meanings in Haskell compared to most languages.  `data A` declares a new concrete data type, like `Int`, while `class` declares an interface that can be met by other data types, like `Monad`, `ToJSON`, or `Num`.  They are not interchangeable.

Comment: why did you call it "tag" in json?